# Forminator + Hubspot Workflows

Tags: forms, api, json

I need to send Forminator form data to a Hubspot workflow for a client. This doesn't seem to be working

```
function send_form_data_to_hubspot($form_data) {

    $hubspot_api_key = 'MY_API_KEY';
    $hubspot_workflow_id = 'WORKFLOW_ID_HERE';
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.hubapi.com/automation/v3/workflows/{$hubspot_workflow_id}/enrollments/contacts",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($form_data),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer {$hubspot_api_key}"
        ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    
    if ($err) {
        error_log("cURL Error #:" . $err);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    
}

add_action('forminator_custom_form_after_submission', function($entry, $form) {
    $form_data = array(
        'email' => $entry['email-1'],
        'first_name' => $entry['name-1'],
        'last_name' => $entry['name-2'],
        // add any additional fields you want to send to the Hubspot workflow
    );   
    send_form_data_to_hubspot($form_data);
}, 10, 2);
```

No contact is being added in Hubspot, and the workflow isn't triggered

Anyone have an ideas at all?

Comment: Forminator and Hubspot are both third-party services, so they don't fall under this stack's scope. Please check with the services' documentation and/or support systems for help on this. See [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for which questions are on-topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that want's to know, I fixed it myself:

```
function send_form_data_to_hubspot_pipeline($form_data, $form_id) {

// Set the API key and pipeline ID
$api_key = 'YOUR-HS-API-KEY';
$pipeline_id = 'YOUR-PIPELINE-ID';

// Create the contact data array
$contact_data = array(
    'properties' => array(
        array(
            'property' => 'email',
            'value' => $form_data['email-1']
        ),
        array(
            'property' => 'firstname',
            'value' => $form_data['name-1']
        ),
        //add any other fields here
    )
);

// Convert the data to JSON format
$json_data = json_encode($contact_data);

// Set the API endpoint URL
$endpoint_url = "https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal?hapikey={$api_key}";

// Set the request parameters
$request_args = array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ),
    'body' => $json_data
);

// Send the request to the API endpoint
$response = wp_remote_post($endpoint_url, $request_args);

// Check for errors
if(is_wp_error($response)) {
    return false;
}

// Check the status code
$status_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);
if($status_code != 200) {
    return false;
}

// Get the deal ID from the response
$response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
$response_data = json_decode($response_body, true);
$deal_id = $response_data['dealId'];

// Add the deal to the pipeline
$pipeline_url = "https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/pipelines/{$pipeline_id}/deals/{$deal_id}?hapikey={$api_key}";
$pipeline_args = array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ),
    'body' => '{}'
);
wp_remote_put($pipeline_url, $pipeline_args);

// Return true on success
return true;
}

function handle_form_submission($form_data) {
    send_form_data_to_hubspot_pipeline($form_data);
}
```